# Can I use an app script to run a range through a cell, and save/export the outcome of each iteration as a pdf?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wondering if it is possible to use an apps script to run a range of values through a cell and save each outcome.

I have set up a template in which I input one value (A name) into a specific cell and it returns details about that input, including a list of dates, times and activity. Ultimately this template will be saved as a pdf and emailed to the person. I need to do this for a list of 50+ names so it takes some time to do manually.

My question is can I run the list (contained in a range in the spreadsheet) through the cell that the template is based on and save each iteration as a pdf, which can then be mailed to a contact list?

Unforunately I cannot share the sheet I am using as it contains sensitive private information.

Comment: Yes. That's a pretty common use of scripting.

Comment: Wonderful! Do you have any input on where I can find out more info as to how to do this? If it's common I'm thinking there may be an example somehwere.

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like this:

```
function sendClientPDF(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var pdfstr=vA[i].join('\n');
    var pdffile=DriveApp.createFile('pdfFile'+ i + 1,pdfstr, MimeType.PDF);
    var recipient="EmailAddress";
    var subject="Subject";
    var body="Messages";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments: [pdffile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
  }
}
```

Note this is just an example.  I haven't tested it and it probably doesn't work.  But there are several relevant examples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).

Comment: Awesome I'll test it and see if I can make something work!
I've previously tested scripts involving sheets and gmail integration but I've always been denied permission to run the code in sheets. Does it always require OAUTH permission tokens or can it be done in another way?

Comment: I never had that sort of a problem.

Comment: Strange I haven't seen any notice of it in any of the threads where I've found the scripts so I'm not sure if it's on my end specifically. I work on a company domain so I figured that could be what was limiting my permission but I tried with my personal account and I get the same thing. I get an error saying I do not have permission to run the first line of code (usually line 2/3) which is the GmailApp class and corresponding methods.
Do you have any idea how to get around this or what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Check your resources menu in the Script Editor and make sure you have the appropriate Advanced Google Services enabled.

Comment: Yeah I've been through it doesn't seem to be anything wrong, at least I can't locate the issue. Anyway thanks for the help!